# How-to have tile actually looking bigger (Openlayers 3)

Tags: openlayers, retina

On small mobile screens, I'd like to display 384x384 "retina" tiles instead of 256x256, but also with the viewport scaled 1.5x.

Tile size handling with `pixelRatio:1.5` works well, however the actual size on screen is the same.
Also, if I set

```
map.getViewport().style.transform="scale(1.5)";
```

Then the viewport is scaled, but tiles looks pixelized even if they are 384x384.
I'm looking for a magnifier here, magnifier that should display well with 384x384 tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, something like this may do the trick:

```
map.getViewport().getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext("2d").scale(1.5,1.5);
```